# How do I rename a file to the same name as the folder it is in?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, directory, renaming

I found similar questions, but to be honest it's all way over my head, and also not exactly what I want.

So, I have over 300 folders that are named, example:

```
Superstuff/notsuperstuff.jpeg
Othername/notothername.jpeg
randomwords/notrandomwords.jpeg.
```

I would like the Jpegs to be renamed as the folder. so:
    Superstuff/Superstuff.jpeg etc...

btw, I'm using Windows 7, I think batch scripting could do this? Not sure.

Thanks in advance everyone!!
 Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are in the Root Folder (Folder with all the Other Folders),

Don't append `@echo off` to the batch file if you want to make sure that all is going well.

```
for /r %%F in (*.jpeg) do @for %%A in ("%%F\..") do ren "%%F" "%%~nxA.jpeg"
```

Detailed clarification on command coming soon.
And as always with the Command Line, Bakup your files before doing anything :)

P.S. Tested, And it works. If using directly in CMD, change the double Percentages to Single Percentages (%%A > %A)

Comment: I would suggest that some code is included to account for the possibility of more than one `.jpeg` appearing within any of those sub-directories.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've got no idea what any of those things mean. :(

G:\Books\Titles\image.Jpeg 

In Books, I've got 300 folders. Within those folders are 1 Jpeg file. 

I don't see how any of the commands relate ?

Comment: How I figured out how to rename a file to the folder it's in, however, I just realized that wasn't exactly what I needed. I need file to be renamed but I need to be able to do all at once. Right now in the cmd I move to the folder using cd and then paste the command. But that isn't any faster than just renaming them all manually.

Basically, 

Main Folder has 300 folders which in turn all have one file. From the main folder, how do I rename all files that are 2 folders lower in the branch. If that makes any sense? 

Thanks again,

Comment: Hey suda. So finally i figured it out. Not 100% sure how/why it works, but it does. However now im stuck with an other issue. Any files that have a " . " or period/dot in their names, only get renamed up to that dot. So lets say " today.is.nice.jpeg" and it gets renamed to " summer.today.is.nice.jpeg". The folders name gets added to the front of the file.